# Python file opening with NameError: name not defined

Tags: python, terminal, base64

So when I directly double click my Base64 encoder/decoder script, it opens and closes with an error, I luckily did print screen before it closed, and this is the error:

[image]

What does that even mean? The program runs perfectly in the IDLE, with no errors.

This is my code, take a look!

http://gyazo.com/69a31e3d63987bb44f4d8d69e01423bc.png

Comment: Copy your code, and the stack trace as a part of the question please

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means? Slack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be your use of `input` which is attempting to `eval` the string that you put in.  This is the behavior of `input` on python2.x.  You probably want to use `raw_input`.  On python3.x, `raw_input` was renamed `input` and the previous `input` function was removed.

One trick that I tend to use in situations like these where I need to support python2.x and python3.x in the same script is to use `raw_input` everywhere and then at the top of your script do something like:

```
try:
    raw_input  # No error on python2.x
except NameError:
    raw_input = input  # python3.x
```

Comment: I added what you put to the top of my script, and am still getting the same error. I am using python 3.x btw.

Comment: Maybe this is because I have both 3.x and 2.x installed, I am uninstalling 2.x now! Yep that was the issue it works now, thanks!